# Jenkins - Selenium Maven test error - Failed to execute goal

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins (2.107.2) to run a maven test for the first time.
Platform : Linux

It is a java program using selenium, it fails on the following issue below.

I have tried manually deleted the directory prior to running but made no difference.

And set the permissions of the folder to be accessed by anyone. ?

any ideas / pointers why it is going wrong ?

```
13:34:30 Started by user Test User
13:34:30 Building in workspace /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation
13:34:30 Xvfb starting$ Xvfb :1 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-28-..fbdir7240341890394839754
13:34:35 [Carspares Automation] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/bin/mvn -f "/home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/pom.xml" clean test
13:34:36 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
13:34:36 [INFO] 
13:34:36 [INFO] -------------------------< Automation:Jenkins >-------------------------
13:34:36 [INFO] Building Jenkins 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
13:34:36 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
13:34:37 [INFO] 
13:34:37 [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Jenkins ---
13:34:37 [INFO] Deleting /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/target
13:34:38 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:34:38 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
13:34:38 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:34:38 [INFO] Total time: 1.647 s
13:34:38 [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-30T13:34:38+01:00
13:34:38 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:34:38 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project Jenkins: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/target/classes/Jenkins_TestNG/GetScreenshot.class -> [Help 1]
13:34:38 [ERROR] 
13:34:38 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
13:34:38 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
13:34:38 [ERROR] 
13:34:38 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
13:34:38 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
13:34:38 Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
13:34:38 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
13:34:38 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/test-output to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Reserve Vehicle Maven/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
13:34:38 TestNG Reports Processing: START
13:34:38 Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
13:34:38 testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
13:34:38 Saving reports...
13:34:38 Found matching files but did not find any TestNG results.
13:34:38 Xvfb stopping
13:34:38 Finished: FAILURE
```

Have run the MVN clean from the eclipse ide See result:
Cant do from command line at them moment due to my permissions on a shared vm.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jenkins 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Jenkins ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/target
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.177 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-30T14:35:50+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/304M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Re ran in jenkins and then have a slightly different error.

```
14:36:14 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project Jenkins: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -> [Help 1]
14:36:14 [ERROR] 
14:36:14 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
14:36:14 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
14:36:14 [ERROR]
```

i can now run the clean from the command line. It successfully cleaned.
ran jenkins again , with the following error...

```
15:40:51 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Jenkins: Fatal error compiling: directory not found: /home/test.user/eclipse-workspace/Carspares Automation/target/classes -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: IMO, `mvn clean` is getting FAILED. Try `mvn clean` from _IDE_ and _CLI_ and update the question with the status

Comment: In the last error, it might be the space character in 'Carspares Automation' in the project directory, maybe remove the space and try again?

Comment: Hi,
 have just tried that... made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add clean to your CLI command.
If you execute mvn test then it should be mvn clean test.

And the issue could be caused by the space you can find in your project name, I suggest to trim spaces in the project name.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone elses reference.

I never found the cause of the issue nor could fix it.

I deleted the maven project in eclipse, created a new one. The new one then worked ok .....

Thanks for any feedback.